# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined" in jquery mobile js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile js

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.droppable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tree.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/MobileStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I am getting uncaught type error in `$.mobile = {};` in jquery.mobile.js and I am getting a loading symbol always in index page even after the loading gets completed.

Comment: remove `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>` and `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>` and try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do not include duplicate scripts. All the min scripted are compressed scripts with same code.Remove them and every thing will work.

For production application include only *.min.js. Having all your JS file minified means they will load faster and hence website speed will be improved.

Comment: you are right, its because of many duplicate with min, thanks a lot for your timely help.

Comment: the partial views are getting affected when i try to remove min files.!

Comment: This is bad advice. In a production environment you should *always* use the `.min.js` versions of the files. Remove the uncompressed versions instead.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan . In production do not use main scripts and only include minified scripts. It will lead to fast application as on client side less data will be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

In your first block of `script` tags you have two versions of both jQuery and jQuery mobile. Change it to only include one of each:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the `min` in the filename indicates these versions of the scripts have been 'minified' to reduce their filesize.